# Gerar lista de palavras com matrizes em Python

Tags: python, loop, matriz, combinações

Estou desenvolvendo um script para gerar wordlists em Python, e tenho uma matriz de tamanho variado contendo uma sequência de possibilidades de caracteres em cada index.

Por exemplo, eu tenho a seguinte matriz:

```py
matriz = [ ["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"] ]
```

E eu quero básicamente gerar todas as combinações possivéis, aonde na posição 1 pode ter as letra "a", "b" e "c" e na segunda posição os números "1", "2" e "3". O resultado seria mais ou menos assim:

```py
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
...
```

Comment: Basta você iterar cada uma das arrays, aninhando as iterações.

Comment: O problema é que o tamanho da matriz é variado

Comment: Leia sobre itertools.product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentado, isso pode ser feito usando a função `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product

matriz = [ ["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"] ]
result = product(*matriz)
```

Assim você terá um objeto iterável que gerará pares de valores: `('a', '1')`, `('a', '2')`, etc.